# codeigniter view not loading using jquery $post

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, http-post

I need to post some values to controller and load a view using jquery $post method, but the page is not loading, but i can see the page in console of browser.

My code:

```
$('#fm_reservation').submit(function(){

    var days = getTimeDiff();
    $.post(base_url+'vehicle/getVehicles',{'vehicle_name':vehicle_name,'days':days},function(data){
    });
  return false;
});
```

Controller:

```
public function getVehicles(){

 $vehicle_name = $this->input->post('vehicle_name');
 $days = $this->input->post('days');

 $where = array('vehicle_name'=>$vehicle_name);
 $vehicle_arr = $this->almana_model->getVehicles($where);
 $data['vehicle_arr'] = $vehicle_arr;
 $this->load->view('vehiclec/vehicle.html');

}
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [codeigniter](http://php-addict.com/tag/codeigniter) You can load the view into a variable like this:

```
$html = $this->load->view('vehiclec/vehicle.html',array(),true);
die($html);
```

Just a note here, vehicle.html is wrong, codeigniter loads views from php files so the view file should be vehicle.php and the call "vehicle/vechicle"

The boolean "true" in the last parameter of the view method, tells codeigniter to buffer the view file rather than displaying it. You can then send the html back to your ajax request as it's response and update the html with your jquery:

```
$('#fm_reservation').submit(function(){

    var days = getTimeDiff();
    $.post(base_url+'vehicle/getVehicles',{'vehicle_name':vehicle_name,'days':days},function(data){
    $("#html-element").html(data);
    });
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

it will not load you view it will output your view in console if u want to load that u can use form post via jquery or redirect.

Example: Send form data using ajax requests

```
$.post( "test.php", $( "#testform" ).serialize() );
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/